# getline() until end of input C++

Tags: c++, linux

Here is my code. It is supposed to get input until end of input and place that input into the string **data**. Then it is supposed to tokenize the input using the delimiter "**#**". I then repeatedly call my function nexttoken() to store the tokens in variables.

```
std::istream_iterator<char> it(std::cin);
std::istream_iterator<char> end;
std::string data(it,end);
std::string delimiter = "#";
StringTokenizer strtok(data,delimiter);
std::string t1      = strtok.nextToken();
std::string t2      = strtok.nextToken();
```

This all works when I pass a file through on command line like this:

```
program.exe <testcase1.txt
```

testcase1.txt

```
S A B #
S -> a A #
S -> z B #
A -> b B c B #
B -> d A #
##
```

output

```
S A B 
a: 1
b: 1
c: 1
d: 1
z: 1
```

everything checks out and works.

My problem is this: When I push run in my IDE I can type the input in manually but when I do there is no way to make the program accept the input except if I press <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd>. This problem also persists in linux when I pass a file through in terminal, it just hangs there letting me type infinite lines.

here is a smaller version of my code that only counts 3 tokens and only checks for a,b and c

main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include "StringTokenizer.h"

int countSubstring(const std::string& str, const std::string& sub)
{
    if (sub.length() == 0) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (size_t offset = str.find(sub); offset != std::string::npos;
     offset = str.find(sub, offset + sub.length()))
    {
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[1])
{

int task;

if (argc < 2)
{
    std::cout << "Error: missing argument\n";
    return 1;
}
task = atoi(argv[1]);
switch(task){

    case 0:
        {
std::istream_iterator<char> it(std::cin);
std::istream_iterator<char> end;
std::string data(it,end);
std::string delimiter = "#";
StringTokenizer strtok(data,delimiter);

   int a = 0;
   int b = 0;
   int c = 0;

//reading the first token and puting it in tk1
std::string t1      = strtok.nextToken();
std::string tk1(t1);
tk1.erase(0, tk1.find_first_not_of(" "));
tk1.erase(tk1.find_last_not_of(" ")+1);

// token 2 and 3 are different because 1 is always the same format
std::string t2      = strtok.nextToken();
std::string tk2(t2);

            if(countSubstring(tk2,"a") > 0)
    {
        a = a + 1;
    }
            if(countSubstring(tk2,"b") > 0)
    {
         b=b  + 1;
    }
            if(countSubstring(tk2,"c") > 0)
    {
         c=c  + 1;
    }

std::string t3      = strtok.nextToken();
std::string tk3(t3);
if(countSubstring(tk3,"a") > 0)
    {
        a = a + 1;
    }
            if(countSubstring(tk3,"b") > 0)
    {
         b=b  + 1;
    }
            if(countSubstring(tk3,"c") > 0)
    {
         c=c  + 1;
    }

// this is where the output is
std::cout << tk1 << std::endl;


    if(a > 0)
  {
      std::cout << "a: " << a <<std::endl;
  }
    if(b > 0)
  {
      std::cout << "b: " << b <<std::endl;
  }
    if(c > 0)
  {
      std::cout << "c: " << c <<std::endl;
  }

          }
  break;
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Error: unrecognized task number " << task << "\n";
        break;
}
return 0;
}
```

StringTokenizer.h

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_STRINGTOKENIZER_H
#define INCLUDE_STRINGTOKENIZER_H


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class StringTokenizer
{
public:
   StringTokenizer(const std::string& _str, const std::string& _delim);
  ~StringTokenizer(){};


   std::string nextToken();
   std::string nextToken(const std::string& delim);


private:

   std::string  token_str;
   std::string  delim;
};

#endif
```

StringTokenizer.cpp

```
#include "StringTokenizer.h"

StringTokenizer::StringTokenizer(const std::string& _str, const std::string& _delim)
{
   if ((_str.length() == 0) || (_delim.length() == 0)) return;

   token_str = _str;
   delim     = _delim;

   /*
     Remove sequential delimiter
   */
   unsigned int curr_pos = 0;

   while(true)
   {
      if ((curr_pos = token_str.find(delim,curr_pos)) != std::string::npos)
      {
         curr_pos += delim.length();

         while(token_str.find(delim,curr_pos) == curr_pos)
         {
            token_str.erase(curr_pos,delim.length());
         }
      }
      else
       break;
   }

   /*
     Trim leading delimiter
   */
   if (token_str.find(delim,0) == 0)
   {
      token_str.erase(0,delim.length());
   }

   /*
     Trim ending delimiter
   */
   curr_pos = 0;
   if ((curr_pos = token_str.rfind(delim)) != std::string::npos)
   {
      if (curr_pos != (token_str.length() - delim.length())) return;
      token_str.erase(token_str.length() - delim.length(),delim.length());
   }
}




std::string StringTokenizer::nextToken()
{
   if (token_str.length() == 0)
     return "";

   std::string  tmp_str = "";
   unsigned int pos     = token_str.find(delim,0);

   if (pos != std::string::npos)
   {
      tmp_str   = token_str.substr(0,pos);
      token_str = token_str.substr(pos+delim.length(),token_str.length()-pos);
   }
   else
   {
      tmp_str   = token_str.substr(0,token_str.length());
      token_str = "";
   }
   return tmp_str;
}


std::string StringTokenizer::nextToken(const std::string& delimiter)
{
   if (token_str.length() == 0)
     return "";

   std::string  tmp_str = "";
   unsigned int pos     = token_str.find(delimiter,0);

   if (pos != std::string::npos)
   {
      tmp_str   = token_str.substr(0,pos);
      token_str = token_str.substr(pos + delimiter.length(),token_str.length() - pos);
   }
   else
   {
      tmp_str   = token_str.substr(0,token_str.length());
      token_str = "";
   }

   return tmp_str;
}
```

**1: How do I change my code so that It will stop searching for input when I am done typing? or when it can see ## has been typed? (## marks the end of the input)**

**2: Is this even possible with my current code?**

Both Linux and my IDE compile with g++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using input streams from `std::cid` to read the data, which will only stop when you reach the end-of-file, which is why you need to *terminate* the input with <kbd>Ctrl-z</kbd> in windows and <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd> in Linux.

The simplest change is reading line by line and processing them independently. That will allow you to read the termination marker `##` and not proceed further (assuming that the marker is actually two `#` followed by a new line).

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
   if (line == "##") break;
   // process a single line
}
```

If there's no guarantee that the delimiter is followed by a single line, you may need to read character by character, but that is unlikely.

Comment: This is where I get confused how would I incorporate this into my existing code? Do i delete my `std::istream_iterator<char> it(std::cin);`, `std::istream_iterator<char> end;` and `std::string data(it,end);` in favor of this? and what code would be included in the while loop?

Comment: @ddog: Inside the loop you will need processing of a single line. The call to `data(it,end)` reads the whole *file*, which you don't want. If you don't care about lines but just the `#` you can pass that as a delimiter to `std::getline` which will roughly be equivalent of what your `tokenizer` is doing.

Comment: @dribeas I got it to output the first the line and ## stopped the input. How would I read each line into a variable so I can check it with countSubstring then output it? like `strtok(line,delimiter) then t1 = strtok.nextToken()`